# telegram bot c# , send url

Tags: c#, callback, telegram

i am writing a telegram bot using c# for my games .i ve made a bot and assigned with a game via @botfather.

when i try to handle the callbackquery caused by start button of the game,it just sends an alert of the specified string but i need the game url to be opened.

Telegram bot api documentation says that function "AnswerCallbackQueryAsync" sends a game url as optional parameter but this is not what we see in the last stable version of telegram api nuget pack (Telegram Bot API 10.4.0 (latest stable) ) , it can be seen in the last pre release version ( Telegram.Bot 12.0.0-beta-03 (this version) ) however it is not working either.

can anybody help about this??
i think its just happening in the c# version of telegram api.

thanks in regard.

Answer (score 0):

if you want keyboard has url

use this code

```
"reply_markup={\"inline_keyboard\":[[{\"text\":\"yorText\",\"url\":\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString("http://YourUrlLink.com") + "\"}]]}"
```